# Correct value for varyByExpression when $_POST was sent

Tags: php, caching, yii

I need to cache a detail_view of a product and I really wanted to use COutputCache or CHttpCacheFilter for that because they are the fastest way of showing the page to 100s of users in the same way without calling the controller again. i just have one problem

- if a user writes a comment he normally gets a flash message and the comment should show up underneath the product but i dont find the correct expression to ask if $_POST is sent... normally i would ask for !empty($_POST) but it seems that its always empty

i already tried something like this

```
    array(
        'COutputCache',
        'duration'=>7200,
        'varyByRoute' => true,
        'varyByExpression' => 'md5(Yii::app()->request->url . (!empty($_POST) ? CJSON::encode($_POST) : ""))',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i found the best way to implement this and wanted to share with you!

every part of the website which should be loaded Dynamically and not get cached you can call with

```
$this->renderPartial('getFlashMessages');
```

in this case getFlashMessages should be a callback Function inside the controllers which returns the output (not echo)

very helpfull and gives the possibility to cache almost everything and still have dynamical content without writing ajax for each part !